# Which is safer - using the sql_conn Flutter package or using a web server as a middle layer for requests against a SQL Server database?

Tags: android, webserver, sql-server, node.js

We are currently working on setting up new Android handheld devices (RF guns) to read/write to our SQL Server 2019 database and are at a fork in the road in deciding what to do. Both options below would work, but option 1 is a lot faster than option 2. If the difference in security is minimal, then we would prefer to use option 1. In both cases, we would use a single dedicated SQL Server login for all handheld devices that would be pretty locked down - it would only be allowed to execute specific stored procedures. If possible, we would even try to prevent it from being able to do a `SELECT *` on any table and view - everything would be stored proc based.

**Option 1:** Use the [`sql_conn` Flutter package](https://pub.dev/packages/sql_conn)

This method would use this package to connect to the database and read/write from it. Below are some examples of the code you would use to interact with the database.

```
await SqlConn.connect(
        ip: "192.168.167.176",
        port: "1433",
        databaseName: "MyDatabase",
        username: "admin123",
        password: "Pass@123");

//Read data
var res = await SqlConn.readData("SELECT * FROM tableName");
print(res.toString());

//Write data
var res = await SqlConn.writeData(query);
print(res.toString());
```

*Pros:*

- Faster development time
- Easier to maintain

*Cons:*

- If our `sa` password were to be compromised, someone could take a handheld off-site, reverse engineer the app, change the SQL statements to something malicious like `DROP TABLE EMPLOYEE`, then return to the site and run the statement. Not sure how easy this is to do though.

**Option 2:** Use an Express web server (built using [this repo](https://github.com/seanpmaxwell/express-generator-typescript)) as a middle layer to validate requests from the device and only allow specific actions to be taken on the database.

The web server would have a pre-determined list of MAC addresses and reject any requests from devices not on the list. Also, the web server would have a fixed list of requests that it could do, so if the handheld tried to request something not on the list like `exec DisallowedStoredProc` then it wouldn't be allowed.

*Pros:*

- All requests would be validated against fixed lists (MAC addresses and requests that the user could actually execute), which means no one would be able to run malicious statements against our database
- Extendable to other devices in the future
- Would be on an internal network and would not be exposed to the public internet, so no risk of outside attacks

*Cons:*

- Longer development time
- A bit more difficult to maintain since we would need to train our SQL programmers on Typescript/web development
- This is another potential source of downtime. If the server goes down, our handheld devices would stop working and would therefore halt production